# How do I properly style a component when converting it to a Custom Element?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm making a website on `Nuxt 3`. I am creating `Custom Elements` from a regular `Vue` component (`defineCustomElement`). The component uses `CSS modules` (`$style.myclass`). The problem is that styles stop being applied as soon as I convert the component to a `Custom Element`, as the component starts using `Shadow DOM` for its display. I know there are two options to style the `Shadow DOM`:

1. Global Styles
2. CSS variables

But neither of them work with `CSS modules`. I will really have to re-arrange all the styles and, for example, create a global table or maybe there is some other way to keep my old structure. If there is no third way, which of the two I have indicated would you recommend to choose and why?